# How to learn max/min value of a sysctl parameter can be in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, sysctl, maximum

I have a simple question.

I want to learn max/min value of a sysctl parameter can be. Where can I find bounds of these parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Good question, and the man page seems to indicate that the only answer is in the individual source files.

Comment: yes. It would be perfect if there was a easy way...